# Does Numba support for multiple dictionary multiplication in terms of `multi_dot`?

Tags: sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication, numpy-ndarray, numba-pro

I need to multiply three 2-D matrices of size 25x25, 25x60, and 60x60 to get a result of size 25x60 using numpy. For fast multiplication, I wanted to use `from numpy.linalg import multi_dot` and also tried to parallely execute it in GPU using `@jit(nopython=True)` instruction.

However, in my program I receive the following numba error.

```
TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Untyped global name 'multi_dot': cannot determine Numba type of <class 'function'>
```

This error is not occuring when I am not using the `@jit(nopython=True)` command above the function definition i.e. sequentially it is working fine for me.

Comment: look at the code of `multi_dot` before you get too excited about using it.

Comment: multiple **dictionary**?

Comment: `multi_dot` just checks whether it's faster to do `(A@B)@C` or `A@(B@C)`.

Comment: it should be multiple matrices indeed not multiple dictionary.